# jquery - how to not trigger event when object has no class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do this condition:

```
 if ( this div has NO class firing on) {

      // do nothing when click on it

   } // else do something
```

Is it possible?

I tend to do this way because it is constraint of coding collaborating with another student team. However, sorry for my question if it is confusing and unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I've interpreted you question correctly, but I believe you want to execute a certain callback only if the element the event was triggered on has a certain class. In that case, you could do something like this in your callback:

```
$("#someId").on("click", function () {
   if (!$(this).hasClass("someClass"))
      return false;

   // Do your stuff here, if we get here, the element has the desired class
});
```

*With this solution, you will capture the event, but you will do nothing and escape the callback early if the element doesn't have the class you are interested in.*

**Update:**

If you aren't looking for any class in particular, and just want to make sure it doesn't have any class at all, then you could do something like this instead:

```
$("#someId").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).prop("class").length === 0)
        return false;

    // Do your stuff here, if we get here, the element has no class
});
```

Comment: perfect! thank you very much for your answer, although my question is so stubborn.

Answer (score 2):

You can delegate and check if element has a class(not an empty one) - now it will only trigger if div has a class

```
$('parentelement').on('click','div:not([class=""])[class]',function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it in wrong way.
add class to divs, you want to manipulate, and then you can use selector, or hasClass.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really vague description of a problem, and it's a really general answer:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if (!this.hasAttribute('class')) { //has no class
        $(this).off(); //requires the use of on(), but removes all event handlers
    }
    $(this).on('click', ...)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't understand your question. But I think you want something like this.

```
if($(this).hasClass('anyClass')){
//do nothing
return false;
}else{
//Do something
}
```

Note: You are trying to accomplish it in wrong way. Try to figure out some alternative ways.